# Cant route traffic through OpenVPN on Debian 8

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, openvpn, forwarding

I have been trying to setup OpenVPN and have run into a bit of a hiccup, i have can't seem to route all my traffic through the server. I can connect to the server just fine but i can't seem to ping the server once connected or have any traffic from the client pushed via the server.

server.conf

```
local 94.23.xxx.xxx
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
;push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

when i uncomment ;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" or ;push "redirect-gateway def1" i lose connection to my server and have to comment them out.

I think there might be something wrong with the way i configured iptables

```
iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 147K packets, 12M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth0    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 260K packets, 606M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         94.23.xxx.xxx    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun1
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun1
94.23.xxx.xxx      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

i will be happy to provide more details if needed
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to move the client.conf from the /etc/openvpn/ directory so when I uncommented those lines it just looped all the traffic of the server within the server! Doh!